# Is there a way to search for substrings in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If there is a String named '**California**' at firestore database and i want to search from android app as '**Cali**' then the firebase should return me California. 
How can i do that query?

There has some function at firestore like,

```
db.collection("cities").whereEqualTo("name", "Cali")
 db.collection("cities").whereLessThan("name", "Cali")
 db.collection("cities").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", "Cali")
 db.collection("cities").whereGreaterThan("name", "Cali")
 db.collection("cities").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", "Cali")
```

But i need a function like as,

```
db.collection("cities").whereContain("name", "Cali")
```

which should return full string that contains 'Cali' substring.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is no query in Firestore that looks like this:

```
db.collection("cities").whereContains("name", "Cali")
```

But for small datasets, there is a workaround that can help you solve this, which is by querying the database to get all city names and use `contains()` method like this:

```
String str1 = document.getString("yourProperty");
String str2 = "Cali";
boolean b = str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase());
```

If you'll try to print the value of `b`, you'll see that is `true`. But the above examples works well enough only for **small** datasets, it doesn't work for large datasets and this is because downloading an entire collection to search for fields client-side isn't practical. In this case, as the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) recommends:

> To enable full text search of your Cloud Firestore data, use a third-party search service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

For a concrete example, please also see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)**.

Comment: Do you think that my answer was helpful?

Comment: While this is one solution, it doesn't technically answer the question of having a Firestore query that does this work. Also, some information you provided isn't technically correct; in the Android Cloud Firestore APIs, the methods `whereEqualTo` and others do exist.

Comment: @WillieChalmersIII Hi Willie and thanks for commenting at my answer. Yes, you're right, I just updated my answer accordingly.