# How to add search filter for RecyclerView while working with Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

So, i'm trying to create app that shows list of writers(image,name,bio) and the thing is that  I have problem implementing search functionality. The guide for working with `RecyclerView` I used is [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/fetch-data-from-firebase-cloud-firestore-to-recyclerview-using-firestorerecycleradapter-5fe6e03e32e4).

Code: MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseFirestore db;
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;//nodrosina kada veida recycle attelos
private List<Klasiki> list;

@BindView(R.id.imageRecycleView)
RecyclerView klasikiList;  //tas pats kas find by ID

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    klasikiList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    getList();


}

            //atgriez ierakstus no datubazes un nodrosina atteloshanu recycle view
private void getList(){
    Query query = db.collection("klasiki");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Klasiki> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Klasiki>()
            .setQuery(query, Klasiki.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Klasiki, klasikiHolder>(response) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final klasikiHolder holder, int position, final Klasiki model) {
            holder.name.setText(model.getName());
            holder.shortBio.setText(model.getShortBio());
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.image);


            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BioActivity.class);

                            //Parnes mainigos uz bio activity
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("imageInfo", model.getImage());
                    extras.putString("nameInfo", model.getName());
                    extras.putString("bioInfo", model.getFullBio());
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public klasikiHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.klasiki_layout, parent, false);
            return new klasikiHolder(view);
        }                       //nodrosina jauna ieraksta returnu

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }

    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    klasikiList.setAdapter(adapter);

}

        //izsauc mainigos
public class klasikiHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    @BindView(R.id.name)
    TextView name;
    @BindView(R.id.klasikiImage)
    ImageView image;
    @BindView(R.id.shortBio)
    TextView shortBio;


    public klasikiHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Constructor

```
public class Klasiki {
private String Name;
private String Image;
private String shortBio;
private String fullBio;

public Klasiki(){}

public Klasiki(String name, String image, String shortBio, String fullBio) {
    Name = name;
    Image = image;
    this.shortBio = shortBio;
    this.fullBio = fullBio;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public String getShortBio() {
    return shortBio;
}

public void setShortBio(String shortBio) {
    this.shortBio = shortBio;
}

public String getFullBio() {
    return fullBio;
}

public void setFullBio(String fullBio) {
    this.fullBio = fullBio;
}
```

}

I think I have to use other `RecyclerView`than `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` but i'm not sure, really new to android programming. :)

**UPDATE:**
So I made something like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            querySearch = db.collection("klasiki").whereEqualTo("name", text);
            if (!text.trim().isEmpty()){
                getList(querySearch);
                adapter.startListening();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText.trim().isEmpty()){
                getList(queryFinal);
                adapter.startListening();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Probably not the best solution, but now I have different problem.. Is there a way to make sub string searches for `Firestore`? Like `db.collection("klasiki").whereEqualTo("name", Ja);` And it shows names where it starts with `Ja`.

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: I have created a specific layout/design which I put inside recycle view with values from firestore each time there is a new writer. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/Z3qgp) is the link on how the app looks like. Basically I want to add search functionality on top so that I can filter through writers as I type in search.

Comment: And what kind of seacrh do you want to achieve?

Comment: Search for writers name only. Don't need to complicate anything.. I can give you my DB structure if needed, but I don't think that it's necessary.

Comment: how do you call the adapter in this class,can you please show me the full code,I have the same issue as you just can't seem to make that work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to search for a writter you need to create a `Query`.

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query nameOfTheWritterQuery = rootRef.collection("writters")
    .whereEqualTo("writterName", "Eidemanis Roberts");
```

Seeing your `Klasiki` class, I need to tell you that you do not respect [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) rules for all your fields and you can have problems while deserializing. Your model class should look like this:

```
public class Klasiki {
    private String name, image, shortBio, fullBio;

    public Klasiki( ){}

    public Klasiki(String name, String image, String shortBio, String fullBio) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.shortBio = shortBio;
        this.fullBio = fullBio;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getImage() {return image;}
    public void setImage(String image) {this.image = image;}

    public String getShortBio() {return shortBio;}
    public void setShortBio(String shortBio) {this.shortBio = shortBio;}

    public String getFullBio() {return fullBio;}
    public void setFullBio(String fullBio) {this.fullBio = fullBio;}
}
```

Please see the fields now. All start will small letter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Normally I try to follow that you have to start with small letter, but this was written in a hurry. Also on your Query, right now I'm starting to understand on how to create queries to get specific info out of DB. But the problem is, how do I modify my `holder`and `adapter` so that it shows only entered name is search bar. I think I have to save everything is some kind of list, and sort that way, or even don't use `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` because almost every guide that I have looked up uses pre-made list to filter the content.

Comment: Everything about search can be solved using the query. Don;t forget also that you can additionally perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single field. If you want more advanced search you can use: `Elasticsearch` or [Algolia](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fulltext-search/README.md).

Comment: So, if I use query for search, how do I exactly implement search functionality for this exact code? Before I had an idea that it is probably done through query, but how exactly do it, I don't know. But anyways, thanks for answering. Now at least I know what to look for.

Comment: You need to pass `nameOfTheWritterQuery` to `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` object and then use this object in your `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. That's it.

Comment: I made an update to the post (Didn't have a enough space here to post a code and question).

Comment: For the last question, see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115422/is-there-a-way-to-search-sub-string-at-firestore/47133345#47133345).

Comment: If you want a more advanced option, you can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6x-ZJp-10)** where I have explained step by step, how you can achieve this using Algolia.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have a problem with this too care to have a look,thank you

Comment: @ora Please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry this is the link to the question,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958847/null-object-reference-in-recycleview I also saw your youtube tutorial but I can't afford to use Algolia.Thank You if take a look