# Firestore array contains query not returning result

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have around 30 records in collection `todos`, almost 25 of them contains the word `work`. Now when I am trying to use `array-contains` it doesn't return anything.

Here is my query code:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("todos")
.where('Workdesc', 'array-contains', 'work')
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
    });
  });
```

Here is my Firestore screenshot:

[image]

Query seems as per docs, but why is it not returning anything?

Comment: `array-contains` is for arrays only, it doesn't search for a string within a string

Comment: if i want to search for a word in a string, then how do i do that ?

Comment: Searching for strings within strings doesn't exist on Firestore, so you'll need to use another/additional solution for that. See the Firebase documentation here for an example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Comment: you mean it is not possible to get results where "work" word is present  ? in no way ?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search (read all top answers, not just the accepted one) and more from this: https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+query+text+contains.

Comment: i read this before but i didnt understood how `collectionRef.where('name', '>=', 'bar').where('name', '<=', 'foo')` works ?  When  i tried with `>` and word `work` ,  strings which didnt had this word also came....why ?

Comment: I have implemented the some on a array,problem is, the value in arrayis `kj implementation` , now if i write `kj` it gives no result and if i give completely same word then only it gives the result..how can i get result by writing on `kj`  ??

Comment: Hi user2828442. I've edited a lot of chatty material from your questions in the past, and you will have received the notifications from the Stack Overflow platform. Some of your material has a needy, begging quality, and suggests you think that displays of helplessness will cause people to pity your situation and/or feel coerced into the social obligation of assisting the less fortunate. This is not appropriate behaviour for a volunteer platform. Please stick to technical writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't getting any results, because your `Workdesc` property in the database is of type String and **not** array. See the quotation marks? If you need a property of type array, then you should save that way. See `followers` property, is an array. Try to save the other property in the same way.

Comment: if i want to search for a word in a string, then how do i do that ?

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47133345/5246885)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52627798/5246885)** out.

Comment: I have implemented the some on a array,problem is, the value in arrayis `kj implementation` , now if i write `kj` it gives no result and if i give completely same word then only it gives the result..how can i get result by writing on `kj`  ??

Comment: As Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comments, there no way you can achieve that. When using an array, the match is made on the entire word (String) and not on a substring.

Comment: Hello,Answer accepted. One guidance needed, i found one answer in the above links - `.startAt(searchName).endAt(searchName + "\uf8ff")`  ,  when i am using this with where like this -`.where(startAt("kj").endAt("kj" + "\uf8ff"))` , i am getting error `expected 3 arguments,got 1`, an argument of opstr was not provided, how do i solve this ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this Exception. I recommend you post a new question, so you can get other opinions also from other Firebase developers.