# How to Search a Firebase Firestore Data Base on Selected Month in android studio Kotlin Language

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore Database Accessing Code in Activitymain.xml

```
    db.collection("billNo") // I think want to add some code here to get the data!!//
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                user.clear()
                for (document in it) {
                    user.add(User(
                            document.id,
                            document.data.get("billNo").toString().toInt(),
                            document.data.get("date").toString(),
                            document.data.get("name").toString(),
                            document.data.get("amount").toString().toInt(),
                            document.data.get("payment").toString()
                    )
                    )
                }
```

Database Structure

```
@Parcelize
    data class User(
    val id: String,
    val billNo: Int,
    val date: String,
    val name: String,
    val amount: Int,
    var payment:String
    ) : Parcelable
```

[image]

I Add billNo, date, name, amount, paid_or_unpaid data into the FIREBASE DATABASE. So when I click on searching I want to get details of the selected month in the RecyclerView. All RecyclerView code and other things working perfectly fine. Only I want to retrieve the data of the selected month.

When I click on the Respective Month & Year in the Following Activity (Screenshot is provided below) I want to get the details of bills in the respective month from the FIREBASE FIRE STORE DATA Base. I tried a lot. but I can't find a solution. I'm doing my project on Android Studio with KOTLIN programming Language.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: When i add another month bill it will also show in the recyclerview.  All datas entered to firebase is showing in the app. I want to restrict it to the selected month and year. So that i will get bill of the selected month.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: Yes. I corrected my Question. I need something like sql query for LIKE operator in FIREBASE using KOTLIN. so that i can search for the data and month. "SELECT * from tablename WHERE date LIKE %$month-$year%". I want a operation like this in FIREBASE using KOTLIN as language

Comment: I got it. I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `LIKE` operator in Firestore. So a query like this:

```
"SELECT * from tablename WHERE date LIKE %$month-$year%"
```

Is actually **not** possible. Because your "date" field is actually a String, when using small data sets you might consider using:

- [Is there a way to search sub string at Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115422/is-there-a-way-to-search-sub-string-at-firestore/47133345)

Or you can try using the newly Firebase Extension announced at Google I/O 2021 called:

- [Search with Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-algolia-search)

Or directly in code:

- [Is it possible to use Algolia query in FirestoreRecyclerOptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)

However, there are two workarounds that can be used to achieve the same result. The first one would be to create another field in your User object called "monthYear". This property will hold a different value than the "date" property. For instance, if your "date" property holds the value of "03-May-2021", "monthYear" property will **only** hold the value of "May-2021". That been said, the Query will look like this in Kotlin:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val queryByMonthYear = rootRef.collection("billNo").whereEqualTo("monthYear", "May-2021")
```

The second solution would be to change the type of the "date" from String to Timestamp. Please see below how you can add a Timestamp to Firestore:

- [How to add a Timestamp in Firestore with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/how-to-add-a-timestamp-in-firestore-with-android)

It's in Java but you can simply convert it in Kotlin. Then, you can use a Query with a call to [startAt(startDate)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#startAt(java.lang.Object...)) and [endAt(endDate)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#endAt(java.lang.Object...)).